# where does pkg-info takes its information from?

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

Where does pkg-info takes its information from?  More precisely, where & what information do I need to put in my .deb package for pkg-info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use a distro that uses pkginfo, but as far as i know there is a pkginfo file that is part of the package. The file will contain all info about the packages, including installation info.

try

```
man 4 pkginfo
```

in the terminal :D

Comment: "No manual entr for pkginfo in section 4"

Comment: I found some entries whilst googling (of course ;-) but it appears that "pkginfo" is a Sun Solaris thing... is that true?

Comment: Yes, it's mostly used by solaris AFAIK

Comment: not all packages will install the man pages, it is entirely possible to install a full linux system without any man pages